# Update Field WIth Multiple Values Based on Multiple Options

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table "Master" with fields called "DFM" and "Target".  I ideally need 1 UPDATE query that will populate the "Target" field based on the value of DFM as below:

```
DFM Target

50001   85
50009   255
50011   233
50012   290
50062   183
50063   150
50064   159.5
50142   187
50143   174
50179   284.25
50180   195.75
50286   157.25
50287   231.25
```

For example if the DFM value is 50142 it should UPDATE the field for that row with 187.

So can this be done with 1 query, or do I need 13?

I only know the long winded way ie

```
UPDATE Master, SET Target = 85 WHERE DFM = 50001
```

I don't really want 13 queries though.

Comment: There seems to be some information missing. Your `Master` table already has the values for `Target` you want to update them to. As you looking to update the `Target` field on some other table based on the values on `Master` or the values on `Master` based on some other lookup table?

Comment: No, sorry if it isn't clear, the DFM is populated but not Target.  The info I gave above was merely the data I wanted populating just so you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Then the solution given below (with my correction) should work. If `target` is not populated at all or if all your potential values for `dfm` have a replacement value inside the switch you can also skip the `where` part of it.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `switch`:

```
update master
    set target = switch(dfm = 50001, 85,
                        dfm = 50009, 255,
                        . . .
                       )
    where dfm in (50001, 50009, . . .);
```

Comment: That should be `switch(dfm=50001, 85, dfm=50009, 255, ...)`